# ALAsset save description of existing asset

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can anyone please tell me a way to save description of existing AlAsset. I know I can save metadata but it is when you create a new ALAsset, not available after initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlAsset framework is deprecated in iOS 9. If you support iOS 8+, you can use PHAsset. This allow changes to existing assets.

For iOS 7 or later, I think you have to manually save description in your database with corresponding image data for detection.

Comment: Yeah, It looks like so.